# Javascript slice file into chunks and send parsed data into mysql via php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, drag-and-drop, filereader

I tried to handle files with ajax, chunk files and send parsed info into mysql via php. Here's sample of file:

```
test;test;test
test1;test2;test3
```

etc.
But php got stucked if i send a big files (waiting time more than 40 seconds with 600KB files)
PHP:

```
<?php
$file = @$GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'];
    if(empty($file)){
        $file = file_get_contents('php://input');
    }
    if(!empty($file)){
    function parser($file){
       // parser
    }
    parser($file);
    foreach($parsed_results as $key => $val){
       mysql_query("INSERT INTO ...");
    }
    }
?>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
    function addDNDListener(obj){
        obj.addEventListener('dragover',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        },false);
        obj.addEventListener('dragenter',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        },false);
        obj.addEventListener('drop',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
           var filelist = e.dataTransfer.files;
            for(var i=0;i<filelist.length;i++){
                var file = filelist[i];
                uploadFile(file); 
            }
        },false);
    }

    function uploadFile(file){
        var loaded = 0;
        var step = 1024 * 1024;
        var total = file.size;
        var start = 0;
        var progress = $(".progress-bar");

        var reader = new FileReader();


        reader.onload = function(e){
            $("#container h3").hide();
            $(".progress").fadeIn();
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var upload = xhr.upload;
            upload.addEventListener('load',function(){
                loaded += step;
                progress.width((loaded/total) * 100);
                if(loaded <= total){
                    blob = file.slice(loaded,loaded+step);
                    reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
                    } else {
                    loaded = total;
                }
            }, false);
            xhr.open("POST", "/add.php";
            xhr.overrideMimeType("application/octet-stream");
            xhr.sendAsBinary(e.target.result);
        };
        var blob = file.slice(start,step);
        reader.readAsBinaryString(blob); 
    }

    window.onload = function(){

        addDNDListener(document.getElementById('container'));
        if(!XMLHttpRequest.prototype.sendAsBinary){ 
            XMLHttpRequest.prototype.sendAsBinary = function(datastr) {  
                function byteValue(x) {  
                    return x.charCodeAt(0) & 0xff;  
                }  
                var ords = Array.prototype.map.call(datastr, byteValue);  
                var ui8a = new Uint8Array(ords);  
                try{
                    this.send(ui8a);
                    }catch(e){
                    this.send(ui8a.buffer);
                }
            };  
        }
    };
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <h3>Drag and Drop file here</h3>
    <div style="display:none" class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Databases are not made to hold files, you're asking it too much. They should store relevant info for you to find them and handle them, but the files should be on your server, it's what it's made for ! :)

Comment: Instead of storing a whole file in your database I find it easier to store just a relative path to the file.